# Automate ggplot2's qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame named df. I have tried building a function to plot the density but get some errors.

```
         df
         A  B   C  D   E  F
 1     asd 29  sf 36  sf 44
 2     fsd 24 gfd 56 gfd 34
 3      gs 46 asd 39 asd 37
 4     asd 50 gfg 26 gfg 23
 5      sf 43  fg 56  fg 37
 6     dfg 29  er 35  er 51
 7    sdfg 32  tr 27  tr 28
 8  fgdsgd 24  qw 31  qw 36
 9   gdfgd 35 gfg 33 gfg 33

 dis <- function(name,...)
 {
 fg <- qplot(name, data = , geom = "density")
 fg
 }
```

I have created a function named `dis` to achieve the above:

```
 dis(F,data=df) 
 or
 dis(B,data=df)
```

I know I can use `ggplot2` but I need this in a function.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Please accept answers to all previous questions if they helped(worked?). Also avoid giving your questions titles like: "Is there an R function that does x?". These risk being closed as looking for package recommendations. A title should inform others what your question is about. Most of your titles don't.

Comment: There are syntax errors in your `qplot` call. Where do you use `...`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help:

```
library(ggplot2)

dis <- function(data,variable)
    {
    # you can use both, or the commented version or the qplot one
    #  fg <- ggplot(data,aes(variable)) + geom_density()
       fg <- qplot(variable,data = data, geom = "density")
       fg
    }

dis(df, df$F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for non standard evaluation([NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)). One could do:

```
  library(ggplot2)
# Switched data and variable name for taste. Personally prefer data argument first
dis <- function(df,name){
  fg <- qplot(!!rlang::sym(name),
              data = df,
              geom = "density",
              ylab = waiver())
  fg
}
dis(df,"F")
```

Result:
[image]